# Firebase database snapshot is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to implement a simple search through firebase database. the logic is that 
When A value is entered in the search box, go to database path of the entered value and get a snapshot value at the directory. for some reason, I have been stuck on this with the error listed below and I don't know what is causing it.

```
<form class="search" action="">
    <input type="search" id="search-input" placeholder="Enter NSN number here..." required>
    <button class="Init_search" id="findbutton">Search</button>
</form><br /><br />
```

the search result is displayed here

```
<div class="container"><br /><br />
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="expandable" id="searchresult">

    </ul>
</div>
```

this is my js code

```
document.getElementById("findbutton").addEventListener("click",  function(e){
    var FindNSN = document.getElementById('search-input').value;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            database = firebase.database();
            var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
            console.log(FindNSN);
            var searchref = database.ref('/Businesses/' + uid + '/Inventory/' + FindNSN);
            searchref.on('value', search,  errData);  // this is dashboard.js:363
        }
    })
})

function search(data){
    var container = document.getElementById('searchresult'); 
    var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    container.innerHTML = '';
    data.forEach(function(SearchSnap) {
        var key = SearchSnap.key;
        var Results = SearchSnap.val();
        console.log(Results);
        var ResultCard = `
         <li>
                <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="mdi-navigation-chevron-right"></i><a name="987"/>${Results.ProductName}</a></div>
                <div class="collapsible-body"><p>${Results.ProductDescription}</p></div>
         </li>
        `;
        container.innerHTML += ResultCard;
      })
}
```

this is the error I keep getting

```
 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Query.on failed: Second argument must be a valid function.

at A (firebase-database.js:44)
at U.g.gc (firebase-database.js:170)
at firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged (dashboard.js:363)
at firebase-auth.js:202
at <anonymous>
A @ firebase-database.js:44

g.gc @ firebase-database.js:170

firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged @ dashboard.js:363

(anonymous) @ firebase-auth.js:202
```

the error is saying second argument is not a valid function. i was able to narrow it down the search() but i cant see what makes the function invalid.
What am I doing wrong and How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you defined `errData` function anywhere?

Comment: @VivekAthalye yes I did

Comment: Can you show the complete code of JS file? Looking at error msg, its not able to find either `search` or `errData` **function**. (Mostly `search`). Is there a variable called `search` defined somewhere?

Comment: thank you, you are right i defined search somewhere else too. so i changed the function name and it worked. i can't believe myself